# Calculate Seshadri constant

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

I understand the definition of Seshadri constant
$$\epsilon_{D}(E)=\sup\{k \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}|E-kD\text{ is nef}\}.$$
I am not sure how to apply this definition to practice calculation, or maybe there an alternative way to do the specific calculation.

For an easy example, let $X=\mathbb{P}^{2}$, blow it up at $n$ points $P_{1},\ldots,P_{n}$ and then obtain $\tilde{X}$ with exceptional divisors $E_{1},\ldots,E_{n}$. Let $\pi$ be the blow up map $\pi:\tilde{X} \to X$. Let $l$ be a line in $X$. Now I want to calculate
$$\epsilon_{E_{i}}(m\pi^{*}l-E_{1}-\cdots-E_{n})$$
for some integer $m$. Intuitively, I believe the answer should be $m-n$, but how do I do it rigorously?

Comment: Have you looked in Rob Lazarsfeld's book Positivity in Algebraic Geometry? I'm almost certain that Seshadri constants are discussed in there, and it wouldn't be like that book to not have a few sample computations (such as this one, at least for small $n$).

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it I'm 99% this is an open problem, at least for $n > 8$ (possibly even lower).

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I will take a look at it.